# Java:how to parse this json

Tags: java, json

I want to parse this json to retrieve the value of `tel` or `user_id`

For example:

```
{
  "status":"ok",
  "account":{
     "0":{
        "user_id":"2",
        "thirdparty_id":"200",
        "tel":"28000000",
        "mobile":"28000000",
        "fax":"28000000"
     }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use to retrieve `tel`:

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); 
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); 
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
JsonObject rootobj1 = (JsonObject) rootobj.get("account");
JsonObject rootobj2 = (JsonObject) rootobj.get("0");

String tel=rootobj2.get("tel").getAsString();
```

The problem is that a `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown at this line :

```
String tel=tel=rootobj2.get("tel").getAsString();
```

Comment: It's not at the root. It's within account.

Comment: Just use Jackson or Gson instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing if you have post the JsonString correctly then it is not a valid json as `tel"` should be `"tel"`
Then you can parse it using org.json as

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(jsonObject.get("account").toString());
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json1.get("0").toString());
System.out.println(json2.get("user_id").toString());
```

Comment: the problem is that rootobj2 is null

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. First, you are not actually descending the tree. Initialize `rootobj2` like this:

```
JsonObject rootobj2 = (JsonObject) rootobj1.get("0"); // NOT rootobj.get("0");
```

Second, once `rootobj2` is initialized correctly, it will not have an attribute `"0"`. Try this:

```
String tel=rootobj2.get("tel").getAsString(); // NOT rootobj2.get("0").getAsString();
```

Comment: I would also recommend checking that `rootob2.get("tel")` is not null in an if statement before trying to call `.getAsString()`. If the value comes up null, you can then handle the issue by either using a dummy value instead of throwing a useful exception.

Comment: i just update my post, i still have the same exception with  rootobj2.get("tel").getAsString();

Comment: the problem that rootobj2 is null